# How to find the line in the input file that caused an error - PigLatin?

Tags: regex, hadoop, load, apache-pig

I have a file a few files with 250k lines each.
I'm trying to load them:

```
apache_log = LOAD 'apache_log/httpd-www02-access.log.2014-03-17-16*' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);
apache_row = FOREACH apache_log GENERATE FLATTEN (
REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL
(line,'^".*?([\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}]*)" \\[(\\d{2}\\/\\w+\\/\\d{4}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} \\+\\d{4})] (\\S+) (\\S+) "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "(.*)" "(.*)"'))
AS (ip: chararray, datetime: chararray, session_id: chararray, time_of_request:chararray, request: chararray, status: chararray, size: chararray, referer : chararray, cookie: chararray, user_agent: chararray);
```

To make sure I get required number of columns I use:

```
apache_row_good = FILTER apache_row by ARITY(*) == 10;
```

Finaly I'm trying to store it into HCat:

```
store apache_row_good into 'apache_log' using org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

In final table there are columns:

```
ip
datetime
session_id
time_of_request
request
status
size
referer
cookie
user_agent
```

and all above columns are **string** type.

And I get an error:

```
Input(s):
Failed to read data from "hdfs://hadoop1:8020/apache_log/httpd-www02-access.log.2014-03-17-16*"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "stage.atg_apache_log"

Counters:
Total records written : 0
Total bytes written : 0
Spillable Memory Manager spill count : 0
Total bags proactively spilled: 0
Total records proactively spilled: 0

Job DAG:
job_201403071023_0027
```

Obviously there are lines in my file that don't suite my REGEXP.
But which ones? 
How can I trace it?
Note that many similar (different dates) files I have loaded succesfully
I will be grateful for any suggestions cause I'm stuck I don't fill like checking each line in the file...

Regards
Pawel

Comment: "Obviously there are lines in my file that don't suite my REGEXP." Why is this obvious? The error you have posted is the generic output whenever a Pig job fails. The first thing I would do is use the JobTracker to examine the failed logs and see what the error messages on the individual failed task attempts say.

Comment: @WinnieNicklaus - where can I find details on job/Task? I can see that :  FailedCount: 1. LastFailedTask: task_201403071023_0028_m_000000. Where can I find any log for this?

Answer (score 0):

Common Hadoop distributions provide "human" web-interfaces to JobTracker and TaskTracker.

Here is how it looks like, especially for Hadoop 1.xx: [Amazon Elastic MapReduce docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/emr-manage-view-web-interfaces-h1.html) -
find out "See the task logs" section.